# Scala List: why the IDEA prompts that Unused expression without side effects

Tags: scala, scala-collections, intellij-scala

The program successfully prints the `3,1,2` but I am curious about why it says that this expression is unused?

```
package Collection

object basics {

  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    var res = List[Int](1, 2)
    res.::=(3) // Unused expression without side effects 
    println(res.mkString(","))
  }
}
```

Comment: Looks like an IntelliJ bug. I've submitted one at: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-260236

Comment: Update: The issue was fixed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps some IntelliJ bug, that thinks it's just `::` - pre-pend method invocation without assignment result to `var`.
Next construction with post-fix annotation works for me well: `res ::= 3`

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Issue was fixed and released in version 2020.3.20:

[image]