# IntelliJ grays out code with `throw` in lazy vals - is this a bug?

Tags: scala, intellij-idea

IntelliJ grays out this code. I think because it sees the `throw` and thinks the code is unreachable. However, it *is* reachable, because the `throw` is inside a lazy val:

```
lazy val handleMissing = {
  throw new IllegalStateException(s"Unbound type var $name")
}
map.getOrElse(name, handleMissing)
```

[image: Same as code sample above]

[Scastie](https://scastie.scala-lang.org/iXTXid5rTTWWzyoy2OqY0A)

Comment: It's a bug: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/SCL-16859

Comment: Similar issue: https://stackoverflow.com/q/65882666/2359227

Answer (score 0):

It's a bug: youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/SCL-16859 [Thanks @IlyaKlyuchnikov](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66243664/intellij-grays-out-code-with-throw-in-lazy-vals-is-this-a-bug?noredirect=1#comment117116110_66243664)

A [workaround](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/SCL-16859#focus=Comments-27-3897554.0-0) is to pull the code out into a separate function.